# Firestore - Save an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firestore to store some data on a webpage, I want to store an array of custom objects but in some way firestore does not allow me to store it. I have tried to pass it as an object of objects but it is rejected. How can I do that?
my code is:

```
function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
}

let myLibrary = [
    (new Book("1984", "George Orwell", 123, "Read")),
    (new Book("Lord of the Rings", "JRR Tolkien", 300, "Read")),
    (new Book("Neuromante", "William Gibson", 200, "Read"))
];
var firestore = firebase.firestore();
const docRef = firestore.collection('books');
docRef.doc('myLibrary').set(myLibrary);
```

Comment: "it is rejected" Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is not strongly typed, so JSON is not strongly typed. You'll have to output each of your book objects to vanilla JSON to store it in Firestore.